# Bluetooth chat Software for windows

Tags: windows, android, chat, bluetooth

I'm looking for Windows software that allows me to have a **bluetooth chat** with my Android Device.

I want send my phone's sensor data (for example the accelerometer data (x=2.0, y=5.3, z=8,9)) to my PC and see the result over there.

Comment: Do you want to chat over a bluetooth connection, or is it some technical term for a bluetooth connection? What do you mean with * phone's sensor data*? What are you willing to pay? Please [edit].

Comment: Hey, thank your for the reply.
well what I mean is , for example I'm going to handle my smartphon'es accelerometer data (x=2.0 , y=5.3, z=8,9) and I want to send this informations from my phone via bluetooth to my PC and see these information on my machine.